# Google Earth client kml html link with command line argument

Tags: kml, google-earth

I am trying to create a placemark that will open a radio station in the Google Earth Client using vlc player and the stream url. If I leave out the stream, vlc player opens ok. When I add the stream argument, vlc does not open at all. (I have allowed GE to open local files)

a href="file:///C:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc.exe http://www.somestream">myLink

I think the quote marks may need to be nested somehow or the space after the exe is causing problems. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

After much research I have found that it's not possible to pass parameters in an href link.
I made a vbs file for the placemark and then open it with the href link.